# StarCraft II FAQs

Tags: starcraft-2

Where can I find the best FAQs and strategy guides online for StarCraft II? Are there already walk-throughs for portions of the single-player game, perhaps as released in other countries, and translated?

Comment: This question would have been better asked a little bit AFTER the games release. Now we actually shouldn't be answering this question until these resources are available

Comment: @Ivo: but people can't wait for these things, just like the game release! SC2 got hyped too much to resist ;)

Comment: I'd almost consider this a dupe of the one @tzenes linked: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/great-ways-to-learn-starcraft-ii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A SP walk-through guide was started on [Liquidpedia](http://wiki.teamliquid.net/starcraft2/Campaign) (SC2 Wiki of TeamLiquid.com) recently.
Not much yet, but it will improve over time ;)

**EDIT:** The Guide is finished and praised as the "best guide you will ever find to the Starcraft 2 campaign" [Source: Teamliquid.net](http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=141478)

Answer (score 5):

**As of the time of asking, 7/22/10,** there are no FAQs or strategy guides out for the single player, because the single player hasn't yet been out. Short of a boot-leg copy of the Official Strategy Guide (which also goes on sale next week) you're out of luck.

However, some of the fan sites do have reviews posted of the single player stuff they were able to see at press conferences etc.

Comment: There a reason for the downvoting?

Answer (score 3):

No single player guides are available yet as the game is not released anywhere. The beta had no campaign missions available. But, for help on getting better at the game I would recommend browsing team liquid's SC2 forums:
http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/index.php?show_part=19

Watching day[9] shoutcasts:
http://day9tv.blip.tv/

and watching huskystarcraft:
http://www.youtube.com/user/HuskyStarcraft

SC2 armory also has some useful stuff:
http://sc2armory.com/

Comment: +1 for Day[9] - awesome analyst - although its focused on competitive play rather than single player guides

Comment: There is a comprehensive list of learning resources found here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/great-ways-to-learn-starcraft-ii