# Starcraft II - Are you stuck in a league once you are placed?

Tags: starcraft-2

I am reluctant to leave the practice league over concerns that I will be 'stuck' in the league I place.  Is this the case, or can you earn your way from say Bronze to Silver as you improve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you are not stuck.  As you keep playing, you can move between leagues depending on how well you do.

I recommend leaving the practice league as soon as you are ready to start "getting better", since the "real" league gameplay is quite a bit different.  First, the game speed is faster.   Second, the maps don't have walled-off entrances to protect you from rushes.  I'm not sure that spending a lot of time in the practice league will be the best help when it comes to placement matches.

Comment: Would you suggest playing insane AI's?  Can they even be beaten? (How?)

Comment: To be honest, unless you are getting steamrolled every single game, the best way to get better is to just play in a league.

Comment: Fair enough.  Time to place :) Thnx

Comment: @ccook you may find this thread useful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/great-ways-to-learn-starcraft-ii

Comment: Thank you.  Unfortunately my tank+marine+medivac strat works well.  Placed me in a high league, now anything but gets me steam rolled... doh