# How do I search for profiles online without logging into the game?

Tags: starcraft-2

I'm too poor to get this nice game but I would like to search players' profiles.

How can one find players' profiles via a web search or some similar method?

Comment: Currently proud owner of this great game!

Comment: WOW after 2 years ;) Did you find a new User info page, that is still up and running?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You could use [SC2Ranks](https://web.archive.org/web/20150821024007/http://www.sc2ranks.com/) (*no longer a valid website*) to find stats on individual players.  On each player page is a link to their official profile page on [Battle.net](http://battle.net/).

For example, my (sad) stats: [Ewal](https://web.archive.org/web/20130330035925/http://sc2ranks.com/us/909938/Ewal)

And near the upper left corner of that page is the link to my profile page: [Ewal](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/909938/1/Ewal/) on Battle.net

Comment: Don't feel so bad about your rank.  We all started somewhere.  Also you may find this helpful: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900

Comment: That page is full of adds, I cannot find anything there. In 2010 it looked different ;) see the archived version at: https://web.archive.org/web/20101127145946/http://www.sc2ranks.com/

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you cannot search for the profiles any more, but on the site

http://www.rankedftw.com/

You can search for the player name. There you see this ladder  symbol: [image] which leads to a stats page, which should give you an idea of the skills of that player

Comment: This should now be the correct answer as the main one is outdated. RankedFTW is an excellent resource and you can search by player name or by player battle.net URL. Do you guys know of any way to search by BattleTag or how to convert a BattleTag to a battle.net URL?

Answer (score 0):

If you ever do need to sign in, you can get a Battle.net account for free. You can even get a free Starcraft II Starter Edition account since August 2011.
It allows you to play online as Terran on a limited amount of maps.

Sign up here:
https://eu.battle.net/account/sc2/starter-edition/

A few more (perhaps outdated) details here:
http://www.gamew0rld.com/starcraft-ii-starter-edition/