# Starcraft 2 Strategy Site

Tags: starcraft-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Great ways to learn StarCraft II?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/great-ways-to-learn-starcraft-ii)

Where is the best place online to learn Starcraft 2 multiplayer strategies? I found a website that you can pay to view, but I have no idea if the information on the site is good quality. It would be nice not to have to pay all together.

Comment: Howdy! We've touched upon this question before. I'd suggest checking out the following question: [Great ways to learn StarCraft II?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/great-ways-to-learn-starcraft-ii)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out, didn't see it before.