# Where to find video of replays from '1st person of view'

Tags: starcraft-2

A few days ago I watched Day9's team monobattles. That boosted my own apm and everything else - I began to do stuff quicker.

Does anyone know where can I find other videos of replays that are recorded DURING game and reflect all operations that player does: microing, macroing, moving map to 'hot' areas, etc?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Great ways to learn StarCraft II?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2900/great-ways-to-learn-starcraft-ii)

Answer (score 7):

You can find replay files at sites like http://www.sc2replayed.com/
You can download and watch the reply from either players point of view or and observers point of view. Make sure you do not select a building or unit while watching and select the follow player camera option and you will see exactly what the player is doing as he plays.

http://wellplayed.org/ is a great site that collates live Starcraft 2 streams, a lot of the Pros stream via Justin.tv and use this site to show when they are. It also has a good feel and an interesting forum.

Justin.tv also records streams so you may find the VODS (videos on demand) copies stored from players past streams.

edit: you should also check http://warpprism.com/ out for Starcarft 2 players streaming their games.

edit 2: Links to players that narrate there live streams

SHOUTcraft(Mid: Terran): http://wellplayed.org/SHOUTcraft

Sheth(Top: Zerg): http://wellplayed.org/Sheth

iNcontroL(Top: Protos): http://wellplayed.org/incontrol

Comment: I know about sc2replayed.com and use it widely, but I would like to hear player comments... and see reasons of his decisions.... warpprism - could be an option, but you need to waste some time to find what you want. but thank you anyway

Comment: What race do you play?

Comment: Sheth tends to explain what he does while he streams (top level Zerg) same with MrBitter (high level Zerg), SHOUTcraft (aka TotalBiscuit, mid level Terran) and on the occasion iNcontrol (top level Protos). I think WhiteRa (aka DuckloadRa) may also narrate while he plays.

Answer (score 2):

I thing you're looking for streams or VODs. There are many streamers on:

- [teamliquid](http://www.teamliquid.net/video/streams/)
- [justin.tv](http://en.justin.tv/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=starcraft&commit=Search)
- or just ask on google with "starcraft 2 stream" or "starcraft 2 vod"

Event pro-gamers make streams too: like Huk, BratOK.

Comment: He's looking for **First Person** VODs. However you provided the right links, but the term VOD is often used for commentated casts like Husky's or HDStarcraft's.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for comentary with the files? If not and just trying to see what the player is doing, then you are simply looking for replay files. In the replay file you can take on the view of a particular player and see how they have their keys set up, what they are controlling and where they are looking on screen. (But this is closer to what it sounds like you are looking for).

If not and you are looking for matches between players with a caster (like Day9) commentating on the game and things to make note of during the games, then you are looking for SC2 casts. A number of online casters do a fairly good job of providing games between high level players and offering insightful comments about what the players are doing. For example, Day9, Artosis, HDStarcraft, and HuskyStarcraft are several popular and knowledgeable casters out there, you can find their channels on youtube and watch to your hearts content (They have a few hundred videos out there each, maybe not Artosis since he does the GSL casting, but there is a lot from the other 3 I've mentioned).  There are other casters such as Psystarcraft, TotalBiscut, and DAppollo.

The NASL (nasl.tv) is also a league that is currently running that provides you with similar insights to matches between high level players. If you catch it live it's a free show to watch.